# Can I separate portions of my plugin.xml file into multiple xml files for an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, external

I have created an eclipse plugin, with a plugin.xml file. I have created an extension to the org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets.SnippetContributions extension point. The xml contents of this extension point has gotten really big. Is there a way that I can move the contents of my snippets extension to a separate file? Something like this:

In plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets.SnippetContributions" file="snippets.xml"></extenstion>
```

and in snippets.xml:

```
<category ....>
    <item..../item>
</category>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.